# A user defined control with a dynamically updating list of years

Tags: javascript, c#, html, webforms

I have this user defined control with hard coded years but I need that to be dynamically updated to start with the given year plus seven years ahead. Is this best done with JS?

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlYear" runat="server"  DefaultValue="0">
                <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="2018" Value="2018"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="2019" Value="2019"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="2020" Value="2020"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="2021" Value="2021"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="2022" Value="2022"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="2023" Value="2023"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="2024" Value="2024"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="2025" Value="2025"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just do it in your C# code.  In your page_load (when not post back do its only done once), you can assign your list:

```
for ( int i = 0; i <= 7; i++ )
{
    ddlYear.Items.Add((DateTime.Now.Year+i).ToString())
}
```

and your form code

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlYear" runat="server"  DefaultValue="0">
                <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>

</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: typo...had 1 instead of an i

Comment: FYI ddlYear.Items.Clear() might clear the DefaultValue="0" pointing to <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>

Comment: this is true, he can not include the clear command, and just not include the hard-coded years in his aspx page

Comment: Well 0 can stay hard coded since that will never change right?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding int values directly to the Item collection of the drop down list control, alternatively, you could also consider using data binding.

```
IEnumerable<int> myYearList = Enumerable.Range(DateTime.Now.Year, 8);
ddlYear.DataSource = myYearList;
ddlYear.DataBind();
```

Update:
If you need to show blank option by default, then here's what you could do.

**Option 1- markup**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlYear" AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="0" /><br/>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

**Option 2- code behind**

```
// add following code after calling ddlYear.DataBind()
ddlYear.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(String.Empty, "0"));
ddlYear.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: That defaults to the current year though as opposed to a blank.

Comment: That adds two blank fields at the start.  It works properly without the Insert though. Thanks!